# MySQL where statement after left join

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I am writing a hockey stat database.  I have the need to calculate how many players were on the ice when a goal is scored.

I have set up the following sqlfiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed8fa

problem I am having is how to filter the results such that only goals that are scored at regular strength (shot type "reg") or goals that are scored while shorthanded (shot type "sh") count towards this total.

I need all players to be listed in the output, even if their number is zero.  After finding the players "Plus rating", I will calculate each players "minus rating" and subtract the two.  Once I figure out how to accurately find the "Plus rating", I should be able to figure out how to do the rest.

For the given data in the sqlfiddle, the desired output should be:

```
player_id   Plus_count  
20          1  
21          0  
22          2  
23          1  
24          1  
25          0  
26          1  
27          1  
28          1  
29          0  
30          0  
31          2  
32          1  
33          0
```

I am having trouble figuring out how the join would work such that I can use where to filter out all goals that are "pp".

Thanks for any pointers you might be able to give...

adding what I have tried.  This is from my dev db, so just slightly different from the sqlfiddle:
`SELECT players.player_id as pp_id,
            COALESCE(plus_players.count, 0) as Plus_Count
     FROM players
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT plus_players.fk_player_id, COUNT(*) as count
                FROM plus_players
                GROUP BY plus_players.fk_player_id) plus_players
            ON plus_players.fk_player_id = players.player_id
        left join (select * from shots_for
where regular_powerplay_shorthanded = 'reg' or regular_powerplay_shorthanded = 'sh') sf on sf.fk_player_id = players.player_id
        union
        SELECT players.player_id as pp_id,
            COALESCE(plus_players.count, 0) as Plus_Count
     FROM players
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT plus_players.fk_player_id, COUNT(*) as count
                FROM plus_players
                GROUP BY plus_players.fk_player_id) plus_players
            ON plus_players.fk_player_id = players.player_id
        right join (select * from shots_for
where regular_powerplay_shorthanded = 'reg' or regular_powerplay_shorthanded = 'sh') sf2 on sf2.fk_player_id = players.player_id
        left join goals_for on goals_for.fk_shot_for_id = sf2.shot_for_id
        where regular_powerplay_shorthanded = 'reg' or regular_powerplay_shorthanded = 'sh'`

you can see my various attempts above to use the where to eliminate the "pp" goals.

Comment: Please  show the query you have tried. (Even if it doesn't work properly)

Comment: can you please explain the logic of plus rating?

Comment: the plus rating is a running tally for each player.  when a player is on the ice when a goal is scored, they get a +1, but they only get credit if the goal is score when the teams are at even/regular strength (indicated by "reg" in the "shots_for" table or if the team is down a man (AKA shorthanded or "sh" in the "shots_for" table).